# Iterating over Excel rows to get URL from Google Search and write them in new columns on Excel

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, google-search-api, pandas.excelwriter

I am working on a project, you can see it in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n0BknZC_5V_rLtDCG-cmM-5xS6m9rkeR?usp=sharing). To summarize it, I am applying a Google Search on the values of a specific column in an [Excel File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17p9DcReqxORa22PzK4Q1vINXMFa8Pxte/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100483323073030473513&rtpof=true&sd=true). I put the links to it if you guys want to check it out.

So basically my code will search the values in column F in Google, and return me the URLs I need in columns G, H, I, J, and K.

Here is the Code:

```
FILE_NAME = "planilha.xlsx"
QUERY_LIST = ("Site Oficial", "Linkedin", "Facebook", "Instagram", "Twitter")
TAB_NAME = "Sheet1"
```

```
def _get_company_information(company_name):
    """Retrieve the information based on the Query List on the given company name."""
    list_links = []

    # for query_item, query_validators in QUERY_LIST.items():
    for query_item in QUERY_LIST:
        for query_result in search(
                f"{company_name} {query_item}",
                tld='com.br', lang='pt-br', num=1, start=0, stop=1, pause=1.0
        ):
            list_links.append(query_result)
    return list_links
```

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(FILE_NAME)

    with pd.ExcelWriter("output_"+FILE_NAME, mode="w", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        print("- Parsing Excel file")
        df1 = xl.parse(TAB_NAME)

        # Get single row by iteration
        for row_number, row_data in df1.iterrows():
            company_name = row_data.get("Organização - Nome fantasia")

            print(f"-- Getting info for company: {company_name} . . .")
            df_company_info = _get_company_information(company_name=company_name)
            df1.loc[row_number, QUERY_LIST] = df_company_info
            print(f"-- Got info: {df_company_info} !!!")
            print()
            
        print(f"- Updating DF . . .")
        df1.to_excel(writer, index=False)
        print(f"- Completed!!!")
```

The output of this code is returning me the following Error:

```
- Parsing Excel file
-- Getting info for company: NORDEA DO BRASIL REPRESENTACOES LTDA . . .
-- Got info: ['https://www.emis.com/php/company-profile/BR/Nordea_do_Brasil_Representacoes_Ltda_en_2321032.html', 'https://no.linkedin.com/company/nordea', 'https://www.facebook.com/Nordea/', 'https://www.instagram.com/nordea_sverige/', 'https://twitter.com/nordea'] !!!

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-7f6b4a1d3574> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sheet_state'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py in get_active_sheet(wb)
     59     visible_sheets = [idx for idx, sheet in enumerate(wb._sheets) if sheet.sheet_state == "visible"]
     60     if not visible_sheets:
---> 61         raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
     62 
     63     idx = wb._active_sheet_index

IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

The weird part is that it seems to work until the fifth row of my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17p9DcReqxORa22PzK4Q1vINXMFa8Pxte/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100483323073030473513&rtpof=true&sd=true) and then breaks down to the error above.

Any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to fix your problem?
I didn't run your code but if your computer is in another language than English, the created sheet in your Excel output file will not be called "Sheet1" and you'll have to give the name explicitly to `to_excel()`, for example:

```
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Planilha1', index=False)
```